# Extrair dados de um .serialize

Tags: php, javascript

Estou enviando dados de um formulário através do método $.get ou $.post
Os dados são pego por

```
 var dados = $(this).serialize();
```

Meu código:

```
$(".formResposta").submit(function(){

        var dados = $(this).serialize();

        $.get('sys/GRAVA.resposta.php',
            {
                dados : dados 

            }, function(retorno){
                $('.retorno4').show('400');
                $('#alert1').prepend(retorno);
            });
});
```

Gostaria de saber como faço a extração dos dados, para poder salvar no banco de dados. Abaixo o código que recebe no GRAVA.resposta.php

```
 $dados  = $_GET['dados'];
```

Comment: Esse $dados = $_GET['dados'] ja está pegando o valor enviado. O que precisa exatamente?

Comment: Antes eu usava assim: $nome = $_POST['nome'];
 $resposta = $_POST['resposta'];
 $id_comentario = $_POST['btnIDComent'];
 $ipRes = $_POST['btnIPres']; Eu sei que ele envia nome= e tal. Mas como faço a extração desses dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vc pode receber seus dados desta forma:

```
$dados  = unserialize($_GET['dados']);
```

dai cara informação passado pelo formulário ira como um array

para ver como o seu form esta passando as infos faça o seguinte comando:

```
var_dump($dados);
```

---

Como o php não serializa da mesma forma que o jquery temos 2 resoluções para o problema

1- função

```
function unserializeForm($str) {
$returndata = array();
$strArray = explode("&", $str);
$i = 0;
foreach ($strArray as $item) {
    $array = explode("=", $item);
    $returndata[$array[0]] = $array[1];
}
 return $returndata;
}
```

basta usar assim

```
$dados  = unserializeForm($_GET['dados']);
```

ou usar comando do php para isso

```
parse_str($_GET['dados'], $dados);
```

dai a $dados ja vai ser um array com seus dados do form
pode da o  `var_dump` nele.

Comment: Com o var_dump, está passando assim: string 'nome=Jos%C3%A9+Luis&resposta=Teste&btnIPres=%3A%3A1&btnIDComent=70'

Comment: entao o serialize do jquery nao he o mesmo do php. vou ver como resolver isso me da 1 min

Comment: Ok, vou testar. Obrigado

Comment: Perfeito. Funcionou certinho com o parse_str. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Pra ser mais claro, irei postar os códigos exatos. Minha form tem os seguintes valores: Nome, Resposta, IP e ID_Comentario.

Função:

```
$(".formResposta").submit(function(){

        var dados = $(this).serialize();

        $.get('sys/GRAVA.resposta.php',
            {
                dados : dados 

            }, function(retorno){
                $('.retorno4').show('400');
                $('#alert1').prepend(retorno);
            });
});
```

GRAVA.resposta.php:

```
      $dados  = unserialize($_GET['dados']);


  if(isset($_GET['nome']) && isset($_GET['resposta']) && isset($_GET['btnIDComent']) && isset($_GET['btnIPres'])){

$nome = $_GET['nome'];
$resposta = $_GET['resposta'];
$id_comentario = $_GET['btnIDComent'];
$ipRes = $_GET['btnIPres'];

        $db_resposta->setNome($nome );
        $db_resposta->setResposta($resposta);
        $db_resposta->setID_Comentario($id_comentario);
        $db_resposta->setIpRes($ipRes);


         if($db_resposta->inserirResposta()){
            $db_resposta->getNome();
            $db_resposta->getResposta();
            $db_resposta->getID_Comentario();
            $db_resposta->getIpRes();
         }
         else{
            echo 'Não foi possivel salvar a resposta!';

            }
  }
else{
   echo 'Error';
 }
```

Acho que ficou mais claro. Quero pegar o dados que vem através do get e inserir no banco.  unserialize($_GET['dados']) não funcionou

Comment: editei minha resposta acima.